# Convert data to base64 encode in go

Tags: go, base64

I am new to go programming language and I'm stock on this scenario on my code.
Here's my example code:

```
a := genreAPI{Genre{"Pop"}, Genre{"Rock"}}
fmt.Println("Value of a :", a)
```

The current output is: `Value of a : [{Pop} {Rock}]`

How can I achieved an output like this:
`Value of a : [{UG9w} {Um9jaw==}]`
which is a base64 encode?

Comment: See http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/

Comment: I don't really understand the go documentations, can you give a working example sir?

Comment: when I try to use this that came to go documentation
`encoder := base64.NewEncoder(base64.StdEncoding, os.Stdout)
    encoder.Write(a)     encoder.Close()`
I encounter an error `cannot use a (type genreAPI) as type []byte in argument to encoder.Write`

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what exactly is not clear from the documentation. Not only it has a clear [name](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/base64/#Encoding.Encode) which explains states what the method is doing, it also has an example.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    data := []byte("Pop")
    str := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(data)
    fmt.Println(str) // UG9w
}
```

<kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cBa9vS2LXV)</kbd>

Comment: the example data is byte `data := []byte("Pop")` while my data is in this format `a := genreAPI{Genre{"Pop"}, Genre{"Rock"}}` and when I execute the program, it gives me the error `cannot use a (type genreAPI) as type []byte in argument to encoder.Write`

Comment: @LeViNcE: You might try to add something called "programming" here: Of course you cannot stuff any nonsense into EncodeToString, especially as you do not want everything to be base64-encoded but only the content of the Genres. So just apply EncodeToString to the stuff you want to be encoded and as this seems to be strings you can trivially convert them to []byte suitable for encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can customise the output of print functions by providing a `String()` method for your type. Either for the whole `Genre` or just for the name variable.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

type Base64String string

func (b Base64String) String() string {
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(b))
}

type Genre struct {
    Name Base64String
}

func main() {
    a := []Genre{Genre{"Pop"}, Genre{"Rock"}}
    fmt.Println(a)                 // prints [{UG9w} {Um9jaw==}]
    fmt.Println(string(a[0].Name)) // prints Pop
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response @tomasz , just one more question sir, at your given example, `Name Base64String` is the struct for `Genre` while in my case, I use `Name String` because the datas are came from a database, when I use `Base64String` no data fetch from the database while when I use `String` the output is not a base64encode. How can I achieved base64encode output with the `Name String` field on `Genre` struct. Thank you